# VBA Vlookup error 1004

Tags: vba

I am trying to use vlookup in VBA. However, it ran into 1004 error. 
Could anyone help me on this? Thank you!

```
Sub lookup()

Dim i3 As Long

For i3 = 2 To 30

If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Consolidate").Cells(i3, 2), Sheets("Group").Range("E2:E30"), 1, False)) Then

Sheets("Cosolidate").Cells(i3, 3).Value = "New"

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Typo in the sheet name? *Cosolidate* vs *Consolidate*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow a non-breaking error, replace...

```
If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( . . .
```

with

```
If IsError(Application.VLookup( . . .
```